# Why I get this error: navgation.push is not a function?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to push a screen but its not working:

```
TypeError: navigation.push is not a function. (In 'navigation.push('Restaurants', {
        name: params
      })', 'navigation.push' is undefined)
```

Explore.tsx

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core';
import { NativeStackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Pressable, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { RootStackParams } from '../../App';
import Card from '../components/Card';

type PropNav = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParams, 'Explore'>;


const Explore = ({ navigation }: PropNav) => {

  const handleNavigate = (params: string) => {
    navigation.push('Restaurants', { name: params });
  };
  
  return (
    <View style={{marginTop: 200}}>
      <ScrollView>
        <Card name="Zum Profil" onPress={(params) => handleNavigate(params)} />
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  )
};

export default Explore;
```

App.tsx

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Explore from './src/screens/Explore';
import { NavigationContainer, NavigatorScreenParams } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Profile from './src/screens/Profile';
import Restaurants from './src/screens/Restaurants';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import ProfileIcon from './src/icon/ProfileIcon';

export type RootStackParams = {
  Explore: undefined;
  Profile: undefined;
  RestaurantsStack: NavigatorScreenParams<RestaurantTypesParms>;
  Restaurants: {
    name: string
  }
}


const RootStack = createBottomTabNavigator<RootStackParams>();

export type RestaurantTypesParms = {
  Restaurants: {
    name: string
  }
}

const RestaurantStack = createNativeStackNavigator<RestaurantTypesParms>();

const RestaurantScreen = () => {
  return ( <RestaurantStack.Navigator>
    <RestaurantStack.Screen name="Restaurants" component={Restaurants} />
  </RestaurantStack.Navigator>)
};

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName='Explore'
      
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarActiveTintColor: 'purple'
      }}
      >
        <RootStack.Screen name="Explore" component={Explore}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <ProfileIcon color={color} size={size} />,
          tabBarLabel: "Explore"
        }}
        />
        <RootStack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
        <RootStack.Screen name="RestaurantsStack" component={RestaurantScreen} />
      </RootStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

But if I use navigation.navigate then it works....

........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

The `push` method for the `navigation` prop is added additional for the `StackNavigator`. You can compare this with the [official documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/).

> The stack navigator adds the following methods to the navigation prop:
> push​
>
> Pushes a new screen to top of the stack and navigate to it. The method accepts following arguments:

> name - string - Name of the route to push onto the stack.
> params - object - Screen params to pass to the destination route.

You are not using a `Stack.Navigator`. You need to install [@react-navigation/native-stack](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/tree/main/packages/native-stack) and use a different navigator to make this work. I would suggest that you go through [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation/) documentation where a full working example is provided.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
 const handleNavigate = (params: string) => {
    navigation.navigate('Restaurants', { name: params });
  };
```

or

```
 const handleNavigate = (params: string) => {
    navigation.replace('Restaurants', { name: params });
  };
```

or

```
 const handleNavigate = (params: string) => {
    navigation.navigate('RestaurantScreen', { name: params });
  };
```